# Blender freezing continuously & using only CPU when rendering with GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've downloaded a model of a train which drives through my scene.
This model was huge, so I simply scaled it accordingly.

I use a boolean modifier to make it appear and disappear.
After I've added the boolean modifier, Blender seems to freeze continuously.

Can a model be too detailed/big? Can the boolean modifier slow Blender down?

Furthermore, I've noticed that when I'm rendering in Cycles on GPU-only mode, my CPU load skyrockets to 100% (which makes my PC unusable).
My preferences are set to CUDA and I only have the GPU checkbox on.

Is this a bug? Do I have to dis/enable anything else?

Answer (score 0):

### The Boolean modifier can slow Blender down considerably.

Especially with detailed or complex meshes, Blender's boolean tools can be very slow. Use caution!

Comment: Is there some sort of work-around? Do I just have to look for a less detailed model?

Comment: What's your specific need? There may be a better ways to make it appear/disappear (shaders come to mind.) Maybe try posting that as its own question here?

Comment: Good idea! I will do that tomorrow. Thanks!